# Dockerd --graph/--data-root doesn't seem to work with systemd

Tags: ubuntu, docker, vagrant, systemd

After adding:

```
-g /vagrant/lib/docker
```

I get these errors when I try to restart **dockerd**:

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2017-08-03 21:20:50 UTC; 1s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 6495 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -g /vagrant/lib/docker -H fd:// (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 6495 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
      CPU: 61ms

Aug 03 21:20:50 badger systemd[1]: docker.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 03 21:20:50 badger systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Aug 03 21:20:50 badger systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 03 21:20:50 badger systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 03 21:20:50 badger systemd[1]: docker.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Aug 03 21:20:50 badger systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
Aug 03 21:20:50 badger systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Aug 03 21:20:50 badger systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Aug 03 21:20:50 badger systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 03 21:20:50 badger systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Here is an extract of the configuration file for systemd:

```
[Service]
Type=notify
# the default is not to use systemd for cgroups because the delegate issues still
# exists and systemd currently does not support the cgroup feature set required
# for containers run by docker
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -g /vagrant/lib/docker -H fd://
```

lsb_release:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.04
Release:    17.04
Codename:   zesty
```

Comment: Try a directory other than `/vagrant/` and it should work

Comment: @TarunLalwani you are right. It doesn't work with `/vagrant/` directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
vagrant@vagrant:~$ mount | grep vagrant
/dev/mapper/vagrant--vg-root on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
/dev/mapper/vagrant--vg-root on /var/lib/docker/aufs type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
vagrant on /vagrant type vboxsf (rw,nodev,relatime)
```

The graph won't work on `/vagrant`. You can choose any other folder and it should work. The problem is because this is different from a normal folder, its shared and synced between Host and the VM.

As you can see the type as vboxsf. This mounted folder doesn't behave the same way. And hence docker volumes and docker graph mounted on this also behave weird. I don't know what exactly is different but I know it doesn't work. If someone knows the exact difference then do comment

Comment: They change the param from `--graph` to `--data-root`. So you are right. I decided to to just make my VirtualBox disk bigger.

Comment: @jnbdz, why did anyone ever think that `--graph` was a good nomer for specifying the location of the data root directory? Found your comment while trying to dig up documentation for this `-g` option that was mentioned elsewhere in some (now clearly outdated) references that I googled up; but that my version of `dockerd` sure didn't know anything about.